# Using BeautifulSoup to get the text after a strong tag, when that text is not within a <>... </> itself

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping this website: https://eintaxid.com/companies/a/?page=1

I've successfully extracted the company name:

```
r = requests.get('https://eintaxid.com/companies/a/?page=1')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

# outputs all strong tags
for tag in soup.find_all('strong'):
    print(tag.text)
```

I can easily isolate the company names doing this:

```
r = requests.get('https://eintaxid.com/companies/a/?page=1')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
table = soup.find_all('strong')

comp_list = []

# loop to extract just the company names from the strong tags, then using the a tags
for j in table:
    td = j.find_all(['a'])
    row = [i.text for i in td]
    comp_list.append(row)

# puts company names into a pandas df
comp_list = list(filter(lambda x: len(x) > 0, comp_list))
comp_list = pd.DataFrame(comp_list, columns = ['Company']).reset_index(drop = True)
comp_list
```

I can't for the life of me extract the EIN numbers, though. The `<strong>EIN Number:</strong>` is plain to see, and I can extract that from the first code chunk above. But how do I get the actual number? The  `98-1455367` as seen in the following screenshot?

[image: Screenshot of page html]

For reference, I'm going to put the EIN number next to each company in a pandas df - but can't really do that until I've extracted the EIN number itself.

Comment: Glad that other solution worked for you.

Comment: You have no idea how many iterations I've gone through in using bs4 and not just going the easier Selenium route haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referring to the [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#going-sideways) you might want to use the next_sibling of your  tag, catch the strong tag first, then get the next item from the context:

```
strong_element.next_sibling    # contains "EIN number"
```

"Sibling" in this context is the next node, not the next element/tag. Your element's next node is a text node, so you get the text you want.

Comment: Like if I do this: `table2 = soup.find(string = "EIN Number:").find_next('')` that only gives me the next tag, or when I add `next_sibling` instead of `find_next` I get `None` - or if I use `find_all` after the `soup.` I get: `AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'next_sibling'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?`

Comment: ok it worked with a simple guess, using `next` - color me stupid